# DataNucleus Enhancer doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm writing a web app using Google AppEngine and Spring MVC. I carefully upgraded to the v2 of the DataNucleus pluging by following these steps: http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo (I use Eclipse).

When I try to run the Enhancer Tool I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL 
"file:/.../eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.4.v201203300216r37/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.0.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL 
"file:/.../eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.4.v201203300216r37/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/lib/opt/tools/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.0.6.jar."
```

I formatted the message so that you could see the tiny difference, one jar is loaded from "user" directory, the other one from "tools" directory. I don't understand why. In the project build path, there is only the one from "user" and to the DataNucleus configuration I added the one from "tools", just like the howto above suggested.

In other cases I've seen around this message was mostly caused by conflicting versions of datanucleus plugin but it doesn't apply to me. I guess it's just some stupid thing in my case... so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are so sure of your build-path, have you tried cleaning your project and re-building ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all, I didn't read the instructions as carefully as I thought. The problem was really that the jars were there twice, one in the project build path, one in the datanucleus configuration. It shouldn't be in the project build path (or in fact, it shouldn't be in one of them, doesn't matter which one). I added it there automatically when I copied libs to the war directory and I assumed it had to be done. But the instructions clearly say that **only jdo-api** needs to be in the project build path.

One thing I don't understand though. In one step of the instructions I had to uncheck *"use project classpath when running tools"* in the DataNuclues configuration. So how is it possible that the plugin was still using the libs configured in the project build path?